# How to determine the url for $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created a JavaScript file that needs to know the location where it comes from. Inside of the script, I have the following code to determine the url of the JavaScript file.

```
var url = (function () {
    if (module) {
        // resolve URL from module - RequireJS
        return module.uri;
    }
    else {
        // resolve URL from currentScript - Firefox & Chrome
        if (document.currentScript) {
            return document.currentScript.src;
        }
        // resolve URL from DOM - Internet Explorer
        else {
            var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
            script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];

            if (script.getAttribute.length !== undefined) {
                return script.src;
            }
            return script.getAttribute('src', -1);
        }
    }
}());
```

I'd like to be able to make my JavaScript file compatible for people using jQuery's `$.getScript` (it's the same as an `$.ajax` call). Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to get the url when it's used. An option I thought of would be:

```
var ScriptUrl = "https://example.com/myscript.js";
var callback = function () {
    console.log("Callback");
}
$.getScript(ScriptUrl, callback);
```

I could then check for the variable `ScriptUrl` inside of my script, but I don't like this solution for obvious reasons.

```
var url = ScriptUrl ? ScriptUrl : (function () {
    // ...
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how reliable it is, but the only thing that would work is to use a `ajaxComplete`  hook and a *magic unique identifier*  at the beginning of your `myscript.js`. This will  not work for cross domain request, because there you can't access `responseText`, but in that case you might be able to scan for the `script` tag.

When the callback for `myscript` is called, you will check if the `responseText` starts with this *unique identifier*, if so then the `url` in `ajaxOptions` should be the one of your script.

```
//unique-identifier
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
  if( /^\/\/unique-identifier/.test(jqXHR.responseText) ) {
     console.log('my url is: '+ajaxOptions.url);
  }
});

console.log('is executed before the "ajaxComplete"');
```

If you are sure that the name `myscript.js` itself is unique, then you should be able to use the same technique for both same and cross domain requests, and you won't need that comment.

You for sure need to add some more logic when your code should be executed because as you can see the `console.log` will be executed before the `url` is known. And you might need to check if `jQuery` exists.

Maybe something like this:

```
//unique-identifier
(function() {
  var ScriptUrl;

  function init() {

    console.log('init');
  }


  if( window.jQuery ) {
    jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
      if( /^\/\/unique-identifier/.test(jqXHR.responseText) ) {
        ScriptUrl = ajaxOptions.url;
        init();
      }
    });
  } else {
    //do some error handling or support an altnerative loader like requirejs
  }

}());
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about `ajaxCompleted` function. How would you be able to determine whether to use `ajaxCompleted` or to look at the `script` tags? Also unfortunately I need to do cross domain requests... but I will still mark this as correct unless somebody else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Good point about looking at the `myscript.js`. That will always be the same so I can definitely use that.

Comment: @Dehli if this is the case then you can use the `ajaxCompleted` because also for cross domain requests, the `ajaxOptions.url`  will be set only the `jqXHR.responseText` will be empty. I would guess - but there I would need to do some code review of jQuery - that the first call to the `jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete`  will always be for the script itself.

Comment: Thanks! I will mess around with this to get it working. I will add a comment with whatever I come up with.

Comment: @Dehli feel free to provide a complete solution and mark yours as the accepted one, instead of adding comments.

Comment: Thanks again for your solution! I was able to get it working :) If you have any suggestions feel free to comment!

Answer (score 1):

I took the solution that t.niese presented and applied it to my original code. `uniqueKey` is a string that will be used to determine whether a url is the script's url. I assume that `jQuery` has already been loaded before this code is executed if the user isn't using `RequireJS`.

```
(function (factory) {
    // Support module loading scenarios
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD Anonymous Module
        define(['jquery', 'module'], factory);
    } else {
        // No module loader
        factory(jQuery);
    }
})(function ($, module) {
    // Used to determine whether the url is for the script
    var uniqueKey = 'myscript.js';

    var urlPromise = (function () {
        // Check if the url is the correct one
        var validUrl = function(url) {
            return url ? url.indexOf(uniqueKey) > -1 : false; 
        };

        return (function () {
            var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();

            if (document.currentScript && validUrl(document.currentScript.src)) {
                // Chrome & Firefox
                deferred.resolve(document.currentScript.src);
            }
            else if (module && validUrl(module.uri)) {
                // RequireJS
                deferred.resolve(module.uri);
            }
            else {
                // DOM
                var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
                var script = scripts.length > 0 ? scripts[scripts.length - 1] : null;

                if (script && script.getAttribute.length !== undefined && validUrl(script.src)) {
                    deferred.resolve(script.src);
                }
                else if (script && validUrl(script.getAttribute('src', -1))) {
                    deferred.resolve(script.getAttribute('src', -1));
                }
                else {
                    // AJAX request
                    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
                        if (ajaxOptions && validUrl(ajaxOptions.url)) {
                            deferred.resolve(ajaxOptions.url); 
                        }
                    });
                }
            }        
            return deferred;
        }());
    }());

    urlPromise.then(function(scriptUrl) {
        console.log(scriptUrl);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];`  might fail, because the maintainer of the page might have removed all script tags - not likely but it could happen.

Comment: Not sure how the `module` should/will work, but if requirejs is not included in the page or the wrapper function is missing around the code then `module`  is not defined and this will throw an exception.

Comment: I have a wrapper function around this code so that line isn't throwing an exception. I appreciate all the feedback!